# Erro: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, para uma requisição ajax

Tags: ajax, cors, xmlhttprequest

Para a requisição AJAX abaixo:

```
var url = "minhaurlaqui";
$.ajax({url: url,  success: function (retorno)
}
```

Tenho o seguinte retorno:

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'urlaqui' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource."

Não consigo ajustar isso em local algum, alguém poderia me dizer o que está faltando fazer na requisição Ajax ?

Comment: Olá Diogo! Pode por favor informar para qual URL está tentando realizar a requisição? Por acaso seria uma URL local?

Comment: A forma mais rápida: Usando uma extensão. Nunca fiz isso mas achei essa. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi Se tiver usando alguma lógica nesse teu endpoint fala aqui, pois é possível habilitar isso por ele.

Comment: Sim, mas abaixo recebi as resposta pra dúvida, que quem bloqueia é browser, de qualquer forma muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não está faltando nada na sua requisição (apesar do callback de sucesso não estar definido).

O navegador que está barrando a resposta por conta da política de origem cruzada. Como você está fazendo uma requisição para uma rota não-local, seu navegador supõe que você pode estar tentando roubar recursos de outro website.

Na resposta do serviço que você está tentando utilizar, é necessário que haja o header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [seu website]` ou `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` para que o navegador entenda que esta resposta do servidor pode de fato ser entregue ao usuário.

Note que o navegador não te impede de enviar a requisição, e tampouco o servidor te responde com um erro, o servidor de fato processou sua requisição e te deu uma resposta, mas o navegador se recusou a exibi-la.

Comment: Entendido, muito obrigado, era bem essa resposta que precisava.